# Create master/detail grids using XtraGrid Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, grid, devexpress, master-detail

I'm a beginner regarding C#, Entity and working with grids, so although I assume what I'm asking is somewhat general, I am a little lost.
I have two tables in my SQL database: `PeriodicReports` and `PeriodicReportGroups`. Each reports group can have 1 or more periodic reports, so what I envisioned was a grid with rows that would have a + sign at the left and could be expanded, showing the related periodic reports for each group. I know this can be done because I've seen very similar examples in DevExpress support site, but although I've put time trying to understand them and apply them to my case, I still haven't figured how to do it. 
This is what my code looks like. After using the Entity Framework with my tables, this class got created automatically:

```
public partial class ReportEntities : DbContext
{
    public ReportEntities()
        : base("name=ReportEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public DbSet<PeriodicReportGroup> PeriodicReportGroups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PeriodicReport> PeriodicReports { get; set; }
}
```

I created this interface and class myself in order to only show certain columns in my grid:

```
    public interface IPeriodicReportGroup
{
    string Name { get; }
    string Description { get; }
    bool Active { get; set; }
}

public partial class PeriodicReportGroup : IPeriodicReportGroup
{
}
```

And in the other hand, I have my XtraForm with an XtraGrid:

```
public partial class Form1 : XtraForm
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitSkinGallery();
        InitGrid();
    }

    BindingList<IPeriodicReportGroup> gridDataList = new BindingList<IPeriodicReportGroup>();

    void InitGrid()
    {
        var database = new ReportEntities();

        var reportGroups = database.PeriodicReportGroups.ToList( );

        foreach (var group in reportGroups )
            gridDataList.Add( group );

        gridControl.DataSource = gridDataList;
    }
...
```

So far, I'm successfully putting the periodic report groups that I have in my DB in the grid, which is good. But I still have no clue on how exactly set up the details grid that will expand for each group, although I feel it should be something pretty standard. Can anybody offer some guidance? I'm not asking for somebody else to do my work, just something that can point me out in the right direction, because right now I'm pretty lost. 
I'd also love to be able to add new groups and new details on the run by inputting data into an empty row, is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you contact the DX guys regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

XtraGrid support three ways to do it:
Check this [link](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3473) for more information.
Basically master-detail is thing that confuses, but careful reading will help you.